# How to loop API pages and compare values for changing markers on map using xamarin.forms.maps iOS C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I want to check each page values from the API and against the values to change the color of the map marker.

This is my API: http://194.141.118.43:3001/?id=0 where id is from 0 to 16

I want:

if from ?id=0 AL = 1 the marker should be green

if from ?id=0 AL = 2 the marker should be yellow

if from ?id=0 AL = 3 the marker should be orange

if from ?id=0 AL = 4 the marker should be red

So I want to check for all 17 stations (from ?id=0 to ?id=16)

I am currently checking the property `Alertlevelwebsite` in this method with this API: http://194.141.118.43:3001/stations, But now I have to check all the values from this address for each pin and I have to put a color for the largest value for each pin.

http://194.141.118.43:3001/?id=0 (from 0 to 16)

I use this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithmaps/) from xamarin.forms.maps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithmaps/ and in `CustomMapRenderer` class I try to change the colors in this method:

```
protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

        if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
            return null;

        var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);

        //Get Value
        c_annotation = annotation;

        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }

        annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Name);
        if (annotationView == null)
        {
            annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Name);
            annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Name = customPin.Name;
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.Url;
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Address = customPin.Address;
            //Add First Line
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).AlertLevel = customPin.AlertLevel;

            if (customPin.AlertLevel == 1)
            {
                annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("green.png");
            }
            else if (customPin.AlertLevel == 2)
            {
                annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("yellow.png");
            }
            else if (customPin.AlertLevel == 3)
            {
                annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("orange.png");
            }
            else if (customPin.AlertLevel == 4)
            {
                annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("red.png");
            }

            //Add Second Line
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).CodeNum = customPin.CodeNum;

            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).MapCode = customPin.MapCode;


            //Here I add the RequestUri for stations
            string GenerateRequestUriStations(string endpoint)
            {
                string requestUri = endpoint;
                requestUri += $"stations";

                return requestUri;
            }

            //Here I need the loop from 0 to 16 every page and change the pin icons like above if statement
            string GenerateRequestUri(string endpoint)
            {
                string requestUri = endpoint;
                requestUri += $"?id=0";

                return requestUri;
            }

            //This is the value who I need to compare result.WaterData.Ardaforecast but does not allow me to write result.WaterData.Ardaforecast and does not allow me to foreach here .. I don't know why ?
            var reusult = _restServiceData.GetWaterDataForecast(GenerateRequestUriStations(Constants.EndPoint), GenerateRequestUri(Constants.EndPoint));

        }


        annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

        configureDetailView(annotationView);

        return annotationView;
    }
```

In the comments above the code I mean that when I write:

```
 var reusult = _restServiceData.GetWaterDataForecast(GenerateRequestUriStations(Constants.EndPoint), GenerateRequestUri(Constants.EndPoint));

            foreach (var item in IAsyncResult)
            {

            }
```

When I try to write `result.` automatic puts me `IAsyncResult`.. I don't know why.. ?

Can I get an example of how to loop all the pages and change colors on the markers ?

My GetDataFromAPI look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<AlertLevel> GetDataFromAPI(int mapCode)
    {
        var listAlert = new List<AlertLevel>();

        var reusult = _restServiceData.GetWaterDataForecast(GenerateRequestUriStations(Constants.EndPoint), GenerateRequestUri(Constants.EndPoint, mapCode));

        foreach (var item in reusult.WaterData.Ardaforecast[0].Items)
        {
            var currentData = new AlertLevel()
            {
                dateForecast = item.DateTimeForecast,
                levelForecast = item.AlertLevelForecast
                
            };


            listAlert.Add(currentData);
        }

        return listAlert;
    }
```

My GetWaterDataForecast look like this:

```
    using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Services
{
    public class RestServiceData
    {
        HttpClient _client1;

        HttpClient _client2;

        public RestServiceData()
        {
            _client1 = new HttpClient();

            _client2 = new HttpClient();
        }

        public WaterBindingData GetWaterDataForecast(string query, string query2)
        {
            WaterDataJson waterData = new WaterDataJson();
            WaterStationsJson waterStations = new WaterStationsJson();

            WaterBindingData result = new WaterBindingData();
            try
            {

                var task = Task.Run(() => _client1.GetAsync(query));
                task.Wait();
                var response = task.Result;

                var task2 = Task.Run(() => _client2.GetAsync(query2));
                task2.Wait();
                var response2 = task2.Result;


                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var content2 = response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    var json = content2.Replace("\"ardaforecast\":[[", "\"ardaforecast\":[ {\"items\": [")
                                                 .Replace("}],{\"fieldCount\"", "}],\"details\":{\"fieldCount\"")
                                                 .Replace("}]}", "}}]}");
                    waterData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WaterDataJson>(json);


                    waterStations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WaterStationsJson>(content);

                    result.WaterData = waterData;
                    result.WaterStation = waterStations;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("\t\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

}

My `WaterBindingData` look like:

```
    using System;
namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Models
{
    public class WaterBindingData
    {
        public WaterDataJson WaterData { get; set; }

        public WaterStationsJson WaterStation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My `WaterDataJson` and `WaterStations` look like:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast
{
    public class WaterDataJson
    {
        public List<ForecastBody> Ardaforecast { get; set; }
    }
    public class ForecastBody
    {
        public ForecastItem[] Items { get; set; }
        public ForecastDetails Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class ForecastItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("Dt")]
        public DateTime DateTimeForecast { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AL")]
        public int AlertLevelForecast { get; set; }
    }

    public class ForecastDetails
    {
        public int fieldCount { get; set; }
        public int affectedRows { get; set; }
        public int insertId { get; set; }
        public int serverStatus { get; set; }
        public int warningCount { get; set; }
        public int changedRows { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public bool protocol41 { get; set; }
    }
}

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Models
{
    public class WaterStationsJson
    {
        public List<ForecastStations> Stations { get; set; }
    }
    public class ForecastStations
    {
        [JsonProperty("Map_code")]
        public int MapCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("NAME_IME")]
        public string NameEN { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("NAME_CYR")]
        public string NameBG { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Alertlevelwebsite")]
        public int AlertLevelStation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CODENUM")]
        public int CodeNum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "does not allow me to" - what does this mean?  Please post the code you have tried and the **specific** errors you receive.

Comment: I update my question.. sorry for that ..

Comment: what is the return type of `GetWaterDataForecast`?  Is it an `async` method?

Comment: you can just ignore the suggestions made by the IDE - just type is `result`

Comment: is generally asynchronous, but in the method itself I use code that converts it to synchronous

Comment: When I write result. I do not see the rest of the response like result.WaterData.ArdaForecast..

Comment: you are trying to use a `foreach` with `WaterBindingData` - is that even an `IEnumerable` type?

Comment: Yes is IEnumerable type

Comment: simply from looking at what you've posted that does not appear to be true

Comment: What can I do to see what type return ?

Comment: this is code that **YOU** wrote, correct?  So you should be able to look at it and check the method signatures

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238284/discussion-between-blagovest-pizhev-and-jason).

Comment: I update the question again.. can you check, please ?

Comment: I think this return a list ?

Comment: `WaterBindingData` is not `IEnumerable` but it contains 2 properties that are.  You cannot iterate (ie, foreach) `WaterBindingData` but you can iterate each of the two properties

Comment: Can I get example with ForecastItems.. ?

Comment: The first step in solving your problem is to click on `var` in `var result`. This should give you a "lightbulb" icon at the left, whose first option is `use explicit type instead of 'var'`. Do so. Now you can see what type `result` is. This should help you decide what you need to do next. Another clue is that intellisense suggested `IAsyncResult`. If you google that, you'll find `IAsyncResult Interface (System)` in Microsoft docs. There, you can see an explanation, and some sample code for working with an IAsyncResult. Also, see any doc/tutorial about working with result of a task.